# How to receive webhook data from clickfunnels (sales funnel) in your laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have created a route in web.php file "Route::any('funnel_webhooks/test', [WebhookController::class, 'handle']);" and have created a webhook in clickfunnels as https://dotapp.itulbuild.com/funnel_webhooks/test  purchase_created , but whenever i am testing the purchase create event its giving an error  301 Moved Permanently, kindly help.....